# rplidar_node on ros2 / Autoware drops message for ‚Unknown‘ reason

Tags: ros, rplidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I‘m using [Autoware](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto) and the [rplidar_node](https://github.com/youtalk/rplidar_ros) showing correct messages (ros2 topic echo scan) but it fails to get them shown on rviz2 with this error message

> [INFO] [1625892725.336256970] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1625892723.515 for reason 'Unknown'

When I use ros melodic everything works fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382178/rplidar_node-on-ros2-/-autoware-drops-message-for-%E2%80%9Aunknown%E2%80%98-reason/) by [heavy02011](https://answers.ros.org/users/77499/heavy02011/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is likely because the global frame that you have set in `rviz2` is not `laser_frame` and you haven't defined a transform between `laser_frame` (the frame in which the laser scans are being published) and the global frame that you are using in `rviz2`. In order to visualize the scan data while using a global frame other than the sensor's frame, you must define and publish (either with a URDF file and `robot_state_publisher` or `tf2_static_transform_publisher`) the frame transform between the laser's frame and at least one other frame in your transform tree (usually `base_link`). Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0